# Unable to install visaul studio properly and toolchains required for unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

After a fresh windows 11 install I haven't been able to get visual studio and building a game in unity to work.

Visual Studio 2019:

After I install visual studio with the correct modules for unity. it shows up in the installer as "installed" but when I turn of or restart my computer it does not show under the Installed section. Also when I open visual studio it gives a "Failed to load common IDE package" error. Referring to a file in: C:\Users"user"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_971410d4.

I have tried:

- Repairing visual studio.
- Repairing visual studio and deleting the before mentioned directory.
- Complete reinstall of the installer and visual studio.

Unity:

When I try to build my game I get this error: error:

Could not set up a toolchain for Architecture x64. Make sure you have the right build tools installed for il2cpp builds. Details:
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun ().

I have tried:

- Reinstalling the current engine version (Unity 2021.2.13f).
- Upgrading the engine version to (Unity 2021.2.14f).
- Reinstall Unity 2021.2.14f.

I think these two problems are tied together but I'm not sure.

~ Rasl2002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/access-denied-for-visual-studio-common-ide-package/962361

this link leads to the solution. you need to run:
icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft" /reset /T /C
in an admin terminal.

Comment: If this fixes the problem, flagging it as an answer might help others. Great that you solved your problem! :)